# Using Silverlight to display images from a network server

Tags: silverlight, image, jpeg, tiff

I need to display images from a network server that generates tiff images. I would like to use silverlight 3 to display these images. I would like to stream the jpeg to the client. Is this possible if the images "live" on a server other than the web server?

Answer (score 1):

I think that silverlight doesn't recognize tiffs - only JPGs and PNGs. I order to load dynamically image from URL you have to do something like this in your code behind:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://example.com/img.jpeg"));
```

"image" is the name of the Image object in xaml.

Comment: +1.  Yes only JPGs and PNGs (not gray scale or 64bit) are supported.   Given a full URL Silverlight can display images from any source.